# PHP mongodb update on nested array with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mongodb

I've thoroughly searched on the internet for this but haven't found a solution.

Problem : I want to update the quantity in this document. Criteria - itemId=126260, accessDays=30

```
    `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("547acfa95ca86bec2e000029"),
        "session_id" : "1111",
        "email" : "aasdasda@sdfsd.com",
        "isProcessed" : 0,
        "couponApplied" : "",
        "countryId" : 2,
        "items" : [
                {
                        "itemId" : 126260,
                        "batchId" : 102970,
                        "accessDays" : null,
                        "quantity" : 2
                },
                {
                        "itemId" : 126260,
                        "batchId" : null,
                        "accessDays" : 30,
                        "quantity" : 2
                }
        ]
    }`
```

I am trying to do this using PHP :

```
`$condition = array( "session_id"=>'1111', 'items.itemId'=>126260, 'items.accessDays'=>30);
$new_values = array( '$set' => array("items.$.quantity" => 10) );

$cart_coll->update($condition, $new_values);`
```

But when I run this code, it updates the first nested object instead of the second.

What am I doing wrong here ? Does mongodb not consider multiple conditions in nested objects ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches) to get the array marker to be in the right place. So your $query becomes

```
$condition = array( "session_id"=>'1111',
"items" => array(
'$elemMatch'=>array("itemId"=>126260, 'accessDays'=>30)));
```